# Angular issue: Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'ProductdetailComponent'

Tags: javascript, angular, mean-stack

**UPDATE:**

ElementRef and fixing my syntax solved the issue in the title. The main problem I'm running into now is that I still can't change the textContent with this code

`ngAfterViewInit() { 
  this.product1.nativeElement.textContent = this.productList[0].productName; 
}`

Chrome's inpect tool is giving me an error saying that it can't get `productName of undefined`, even though the intended value of `productName of undefined` can be displayed in the app using interpolation with the very same array in the very same files that are rejecting the code above. I would just do it that way, but I need the array indexes to be dependent on what element the user clicks and the only approach I know is JavaScript functions. I'm trying to get the above line of code to work before I start on those.

I don't understand how it can be undefined and still 'selectively' do what its told. Well, I can kind of understand. It's probably because I'm messing up.

**Original question:**

I'm currently working on one of the final steps of an angular project I'm doing to learn MEAN stack. The project is basically a product list where product names and details for each product are taken from a noSQL database. The product names are put in elements on a `ProductComponent` to make a clickable list, and based on what product name/html element the user clicks, details exclusive to that product will be displayed by the `ProductdetailComponent`.

In my studying, I've found that `ViewChild` is the way to do this. However, as the title says, I cannot seem to reference the `nativeElement` property.

I want to change the textcontent of the div that has `#product1` on `productdetail.component.html`, but before I can do that, I have to manage to access the element. I'm appreciative of any help. Here is what I think is the relevant code, and the error is:

```
ERROR in src/app/productdetail/productdetail.component.ts(42,27): error TS2339: Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'ProductdetailComponent'.
```

**productdetail.component.ts**

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { Product } from '../product';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-productdetail',
  templateUrl: './productdetail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./productdetail.component.css'],
  providers: [ DataService ]
})

export class ProductdetailComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ProductdetailComponent) product1: ProductdetailComponent;
  productList: Product[]=[];
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  getProduct(){
    this.dataService.getproductList()
    .subscribe(
      products => {
        this.productList = products;
      }
    )
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getProduct();
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.product1.nativeElement);
  }
}
```

**productdetail.component.html**

```
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="home">Home</a>
    <a href="products">Products</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Product Detail</a>
</div>   

<p>
  productdetail works!
</p>

<div id="product" #product1 > No </div>
```

My aim is to make that "No" display as something else.

Comment: You can change the content of the div with [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation----), without referring to the element in code. If you want to refer to it nonetheless, you should change the code to: `@ViewChild("product1") product1: ElementRef`.

Comment: Thanks! ElementRef works. I don't know enough about interpolation to use it to respond to user input. I'm going to need to learn more, because I'm finding out that ElementRef isn't recommended for this. It's working for the purpose of familiarizing myself with Angular, though. The main problem I'm running into now is that I still can't change the textContent with `ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.product1.nativeElement.textContent = this.productList[0].productName;
  }`

Comment: You should use `innerHTML` instead of `textContent`. Interpolation is much easier: (1) define a public string member in your class: `public textContent: string = "Hello world";`, (2) insert the content of that variable in the template: `<div>{{ textContent }}</div>`; you should see the content when you run the application, (3) change the value of `textContent` at any moment in the code and the HTML output will adjust automatically.

Comment: I've tried defining `textContent` in multiple files(the data service, and`productdetail.component.ts`). I can get the value of `textContent` to display with interpolation, but I can't pass `textContent` as a parameter of an onClick function with the `productList` array. I don't know any other way to do this.

Comment: You should use Angular event binding: `(click)="decideDetail(textContent, productList[0].productDescription)"`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Now the error I'm getting is `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'productName' of undefined` in `ProductsComponent.html` at the line where I use interpolation to make it display in the app. The thing is, it displays the value that the error is basically telling me doesn't exist. The function isn't changing `textContent`. Is that why? Or is that just the inspect tool not knowing what to do with the framework?

The function looks like 

`function decideDetail(a, b){
    
    a = b;
 
   };` That's all the function needs to be, right? The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: What is your interpolation code?

Comment: This is the entire line
` <div class="col-xl-6" id="0" (click) ="decideDetail(textContent, productList[0].productDescription)"><a routerLink="detail" style="color: orange"> {{ productList[0].productName }} </a></div>`

Comment: You can try `{{ productList[0]?.productName }}`. The value is retrieved several times; the list may not be ready the first time Angular tries to get it.

Comment: Thanks. You've helped me a lot. That gets rid of that error and takes care of this question in general. Now I realize I have a completely different issue with making sure function parameters are completely in place. I need to open a new question with a more accurate title and explanation for the issue I'm having now. You've solved this one.